# When returning a VO from a controller, how do you name it?

Tags: java, json, spring, web

When returning a VO from a controller, how do you name it?

Here is my controller source.

```
@GetMapping(value= "/railInfo.do")
public RailVO getRailInfo(@RequestParam String railId){
    RailVO rail = new RailVO();
    rail.setRailLength("91300");
    rail.setRailDesc("xxx");

    List<RobotVO> robotList = new ArrayList<RobotVO>();
    robot.setStationPosition("21300");
    robot.setStartPosition("0");
    robot.setEndPosition("30000");
    robotList.add(robot);
    robot.setStationPosition("51300");
    robot.setStartPosition("30000");
    robot.setEndPosition("60000");
    robotList.add(robot);
    robot.setStationPosition("81300");
    robot.setStartPosition("60000");
    robot.setEndPosition("91300");
    robotList.add(robot);

    rail.setRobotVO(robotList);

    return rail;
}
```

Here are the results:

```
{
    "railLength": "91300",
    "railDesc": "xxx",
    "robotVO": [
        {
            "stationPosition": "21300",
            "startPosition": "0",
            "endPosition": "30000"
        },
        {
            "stationPosition": "51300",
            "startPosition": "30000",
            "endPosition": "60000"
        },
        {
            "stationPosition": "81300",
            "startPosition": "60000",
            "endPosition": "91300"
        }
    ]
}
```

But the result I want is:

```
{
    "railLength": "91300",
    "railDesc": "Rails patrolling by robots 1, 2, 3, guard post ~ xx",
    "rbtInfo": [
        "R01":{
            "stationPosition": "21300",
            "startPosition": "0",
            "endPosition": "30000"
        },
        "R02":{
            "stationPosition": "51300",
            "startPosition": "30000",
            "endPosition": "60000"
        },
        "R03":{
            "stationPosition": "81300",
            "startPosition": "60000",
            "endPosition": "91300"
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, the data type of robotVO is `List<RobotVO>`. But I don't want to change this data structure, but I want to give and change the name as above in json.

Comment: You change the name of _the property_ `robotV0` to `rbtInfo`.

Comment: Not only that, I want to add names like R01, R02, R03, etc.

Answer (score 2):

use a Map named rbtInfo istead of the robotVO List

the attribute in the json result is not defined by the name of the type. It is defined by the name of your attribute/varible